# Determining factors of numbers when sum of divisors are not larger than the number, program will not accept a limit larger than 10000

Tags: c++

When I change my limit from 100 to 1,000,000, it does not print out all numbers, it stops at a 5 digit number and won't compute any higher. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{

const int limit = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 100;
const int badness = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 1;


for (int num = 2; num < limit; num++) {

    int total = 1;

    for (int factor = 2; factor * factor <= num; factor++) {

        if (num % factor == 0) {
            total += factor;


            if (factor * factor != num) {
                total += (num / factor);
            }
        }


        }

        if (abs(num - total) <= abs(badness)) {

            cout << num << " " << flush;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/wVQraB).

Comment: You're probably using a compiler which has a 16-bit `int` type - which typically cannot support a value over `32767` or so.   Behaviour is undefined if such a type is overflowed (i.e. an attempt to store a value larger than it can represent).  Built-in types like `int`, `long`, etc all have a finite range of values that they can support.   For `int`, the standard does not require a range of values outside -32767 to 32767  (although a fair few recent implementations DO support larger ranges, those ranges are still finite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

It's likely because you are using an int.

Try using a long instead or an unsigned long